# Display same modal form for different db entities

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

I have several entities which are implemented a `IEntity` interface (in real world I have 10 entities).

```
public interface IEntity
{
    short Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public partial class Part: IEntity { }
public partial class Localization : IEntity { }
```

I'm displaying a list of each entity (in a table) and I want to display a modal form to edit the name of entities, without code duplication.

So I have a partial view to display the list and a button to launch the modal form :

```
@model IEnumerable<IEntity>


@foreach (IEntity item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button  data-id="@item.Id" onclick="editEntity(this)">
                <i class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
//Here the modal container part
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="editModalContainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the modal form is also a partial view (simplified here) :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    <button type="submit" id="submitEdit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>  
}
```

At this time I'm rendering the modal via ajax this way :

```
function editEntity(clickedEntity) {
//I need the type of entity to get right modal title and so on
var type = $(clickedEntity).closest("div").attr('data-entityType');
var entityId = $(clickedEntity).attr('data-id');

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Defaults/GetEntityModal",
    data: { id: entityId, entityType: type },
    success: function (response) {  
        $("#editModalContainer").html(response);
        $("#editModal").modal('show');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("failure");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

and the method of the controller is :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetEntityModal(EditEntityModalView entityModel)
{
    IEntity entity = _entitiesService.GetEntity(entityModel.EntityType, entityModel.Id);
    entityModel.Name = entity.Name;
    return PartialView("_ModifyEntityModal", entityModel);
}
```

But I'm encounter a lot of troubles in the next step for the server-side validation of the modal model.

So my question is, in that case is it the right way to render the modal or do I have to make a form for each entry in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way, but the modal view has to be first rendered before being updated by ajax :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="editModalContainer">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_ModifyEntityModal", Model.EditEntityModalView);}
    </div>
</div>
```